# Facebook OpenGraph API: Can I Silently Send a Request from One User to Another?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I send a facebook app requests from one mobile user to another using the Graph API?

I have looked at facebooks documentation but the only options I have found are to A) send an app to user message from the app (which I can't get working) or B) to use the request dialog, which doesn't seem to let me send a request to a single user.

FB has instructions for how to build a custom "Multi-Friend Selector" but apparently not for mobile.

I have tried using HTTP POSTing to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/%s?access_token= ...
```

with POST data set to

```
message='Test Message'
```

but I get

```
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#2) Failed to create any app request"
```

I have also tried in the Graph API Explorer but I get the same thing.

I don't want to send these messages to users that have installed the app and I don't mind the user having to provide confirmation for the FBFrictionlessRecipientCache. Also, my app is in Sandbox mode, but I only need to send the requests to the other developers.

I am looking for anything that will let me do multi-friend selectors or ask for lives, or get help from a friend, like I see in several mobile games these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession from FBWebDialogs.

You must specify a "to" parameter to identify the recipient, and you must use the FBFrictionlessRecipientCache.

The "to" parameter identifies the recipient. It stops the select user dialog from appearing.

The first time you send the request to each recipient the user will have to grant permission. After that, the FBFrictionlessRecipientCache will allow the request to be sent relatively silently (a dialog pops up briefly and goes away by itself).